# Is finite measure necessary?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

I study [http://web.stanford.edu/~eugeniam/math205a/L3.pdf](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eeugeniam/math205a/L3.pdf) proposition 2.1. Assumes $\nu$ must be finite for absolute continuity iff epsilon delta continuity? Can theorem hold for  sigma finite or infinite ? It applies finiteness for the limit theorem but is there example that theorem not true for not finite $\nu$?

Comment: Offhand I do not see a reason for the finiteness assumption. This stuff becomes more complex if measures are assumed only to be finitely additive; maybe they are thinking about that.

Comment: @leslietownes my guess is lebesgue-stieljes doesn't work for theorem bc of cantor function and bc R is not finite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try
\begin{align}
\mu(E) &= \int_E\;dx,\qquad\text{(Lebesgue measure)}\\
\nu(E) &= \int_E x^2\;dx
\end{align}
Compare two possible definitions for $\nu \ll \mu$:
(a) $\forall E\;\big(\mu(E)=0 \Longrightarrow \nu(E) = 0\big)$
(b) $\forall \epsilon > 0\; \exists \delta > 0\; \forall E\;\big(
\mu(E) < \delta \Longrightarrow \nu(E) < \epsilon\big)$

We claim (a) is true but (b) is false.

(b)  Take $\epsilon = 1$.  We claim there is no $\delta$ which works.
Let $\delta > 0$ be a candidate.  Then
for any $n > 0$, the set $E = [n,n+\delta/2)$ satisfies
$$
\mu(E) = \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta
\\
\nu(E) = \int_n^{n+\delta/2} x^2\;dx > \int_n^{n+\delta/2} n^2\;dx
= \frac{\delta}{2}\;n^2
$$
There is $n>0$ so that $\frac{\delta}{2}n^2 > 1 = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

How about $X=\mathbb{N}$ and
$$\mu(A) = \sum_{k\in A} 2^{-k}$$
$$\nu(A) = \sum_{k\in A} 1$$
($\nu$ is counting measure and $\mu$ puts weight $2^{-k}$ on the point $k$).

If $\mu(A) = 0$ then we must have $A=\varnothing$ and $\nu(A) = 0$, so it is true that $\nu \ll \mu$.

But the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criterion does not hold, e.g. for $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. (No matter what $\delta>0$ we take, there is some $k$ such that $\mu(\{k\}) = 2^{-k} < \delta$, but $\nu(\{k\}) = 1 > \varepsilon$.)

This example shows that the theorem does not hold for only $\sigma$-finite measures $\nu$.

---

The finiteness assumption enters in the proof where the $\sigma$-continuity of $\nu$ from above is used.